# Python gives ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy.util._collections in pycharm

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pycharm

I have installed sqlalchemy in my pathon. Im running python 2.7.15
When I execute my test program it says;

> ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy.util._collections

I have installed  modules with my python version.

- Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.3.2
- SQLAlchemy   1.2.2

WHy do I get this error in pycharm. PyCharm run configurations picks correct python version.
In console i tried the import statement it works.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15
>>> from sqlalchemy.util import _collections
>>>
```

Why I get this error in pycharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to Pywren [1] library which could not import some 3 rd party libraries. Not a Python/PyCharm issue

[1]https://github.com/pywren

[2]https://github.com/pywren/pywren/issues/253

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would check is that you're using the correct Python environment in PyCharm.

Use the `which python` function in your console to see the path to the python executing in your terminal and make sure that it lines up with the path under **"External Libraries"** in your project view. You may not have `sqlalchemy` installed on the Python executable in your Pycharm Project. I've had similar issues in the past where I had Python installed alongside Anaconda.

Also consider dropping a `requirements.txt` file into the root level of your project in Pycharm. If your Python environment doesn't have the library installed it will generally prompt you to install it. Just add in a single line into your `requirements.txt` file with `sqlalchemy`. Using echo you could create this file using the following command

```
echo "sqlalchemy" >> requirements.txt
```

Comment: I checked looks fine.Under External Libraries I see site-packages where I see sqlalchemy. If 'sqlalchemy' module is not installed it has to throw //ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy.// error . Isn't it? But I get //No module named sqlalchemy.util._collections// error